# How to modify your CSS working with Mobile Angular UI and Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less, stylesheet

I know that my question has already a huge number of topics, but I think it could be helpful for the community to have a clear answer in one topic.

This is about modifying your CSS while using Mobile Angular UI, with a bootstrap template.

1. This is how a project is organized with Mobile Angular UI :

   - bin
   - bower_components
   - hooks
   - node_modules
   - platforms
   - plugins
   - src
   - www

I have my index.html in **src/html/** and my other webpages in **src/templates**.
My index importations look like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.min.css" />
```

thanks to that, I can see the bootstrap template on my webpages. But I don't know how to modify it. The two solutions I saw are creating a **design.css** and import it after the two other .css, but it doesn't work. 
I also saw that normally we should import **bootstrap.min.css**, but it has no effect on my webpages.

So How could I modify the global design for my webpages, like for example the background color, keeping the Bootstrap template ? Shall we go into the **less files** ? What's the aim of these two css **responsive.min** and **app.min** ?

**How should we organize the CSS files while working with Mobile Angular UI ?**

Thanks a lot !

Comment: just add your custom stylesheets after the framework ones, i really don't see the point of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said, it doesn't take into account my custom stylesheet, when I import design.css in my index.html, it doesn't change anything. My question is how to overwrite your Bootstrap template.

Comment: Yes I read well but this is strange behavior, it should works. some properties are persistent, meaning they will not change after being defined but that is where `!important` becomes handy. IMHO you shouldn't modify the less files of the bootstrap, bootstrap is consistent and it doesn't make sense to modify it just to fit your own design, it is a framework.

Comment: What if I want to add new features ? Do I need to modify the app.min.css file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, which version of **Mobile angular UI** are you using ? I think those stylesheets are not available. I have *git cloned* the project, and i can't see them.

And now I can answer your question. If you download the framework well, you will have a `src` directory. In this `src` directory you have `less/variables.less`, where you can change most of the customizable elements of your interface.

Then you `gulp build` again to have appropriate `dist/css/*.css` elements.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can modify the bootstrap components ! How stupid, I didn't `gulp build`at each team. Because at the contrary HTML and JS can be directly change without rebuilding.